# How to get multiple value from one textbox?

Tags: asp.net, javascript

I have created web application and textbox as a textarea. I am using javascript for validation. When I enter value in text box so it should be number not alphabet I have use textmode is multiple line.

My problem is that how I get multiple value from textbox and store in array in javascript and check each value is number or not. I am using the web form. Please help me.

Comment: This question is fairly hard to read... could you reformulate it? What have you tried? Do you have some code we could see?

Comment: **how i get multiple value from textbox**, what do you mean by this. Are you using a seperator for the words in a textarea?

Comment: Actually i uset the textbox and set its textmode property is multiline so i can insert multiple line but i wanna check each line should be number not alphabet that's why i m using javascript for create a function to validate it.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the value from a textarea like

```
var txtvalue = document.getElementById("txtareaid").value
```

and if are using a separator then something like

```
var txtvaluearray = document.getElementById("txtareaid").value.split(';')
```

will get you all the values in an array if the seperator is `;`

***Edit***

As per your update you can use `\n` as the separator and as pointed by @Sohnee you can do the validation.

Answer (score 0):

As addition to rahul:

If you want the values in the textarea seperated by line, you can use \r\n as the splitter.

Answer (score 0):

This is a starter for ten.

```
var textValues = document.getElementById("mytextarea").value.split("\n");
for (var i = 0; i < textValues.length; i++) {
    if (isNaN(textValues[i])) {
        alert(textValues[i] + " is not a number.";
    }
}
```